# Special characters contained in AES encryption output

Tags: encryption, aes

I tried to find the list of possible characters that are contained in the encrypted output after AES 256 bit encryption. But, it seems like they are not on the internet? Mind to help? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The output of an AES cipher is not character data, it is simply bytes. The output should be indistinguishable from random data.

You can represent the output as a string by encoding it as Base64 or Hex if you like.